# Create a Ruby method that applies an operation on arrays of integers

Tags: ruby

EDIT: ok, I misunderstood the task. sorry.

I really can't find anything else on the web and don't get it myself.
I want to to delete the odd-numbered entries from an array of integers with a method in Ruby. But I get only errors right at the point where I define the method. How can I make the method understand this?

```
def even
  a=[]
  i=0
  while i<=a.length
    a[i]%2 == 1
        a.delete(a[i])
        i+=i
  end
end
even([1,2,3])
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I don't get any "errors right at the point where I define the method". Also, what do you mean by "odd-numbered entries"? I would interpret this as the odd indices, but from the looks of your code, it seems you are looking for odd entries.

Comment: "I get errors" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use Ruby array reject method like below,

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
arr.reject{|v| v%2 == 1}
# => [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Use `v.odd?` instead:)

Answer (score 0):

in ruby it is usually easier to think in a more functional way. In your case, you want to iterate through the list of elements, selecting the ones that are even. To iterate through a list and select elements using a predicate, use `select`. A number already has a method to check if it is even (`even?`). So the solution is quite simple:

```
[1,2,3].select(&:even?)
```

that returns a new list with only the even numbers. If you want to modify the list in place, use `select!` instead.